# Why not use a GitHub gist to distribute files?

Tags: github, gist

The GitHub platform serves the raw content of a file from a gist in response to CORS request. That is, the following code, run in a browser, prints the contents of the file:

```js
fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/theGove/e7c158b8544aaacf2e2dce2a6acfcd52/raw/43e3e1c569866a45eb28204ea32a927158b21b54/code.js')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

It seems to me that I could use that URL to access the file from any front end, free of charge. Is there a reason not to do this? What are the condidtions where GitHub would refuse to serve the file?

Comment: "Is there a reason not to do this?" - yes, that's not fair use. Also github can take your gists down at any time and your app will break.

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.github.com/en/site-policy/acceptable-use-policies/github-acceptable-use-policies#9-excessive-bandwidth-use

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Thanks for the link to policies.  Very helpful.

Comment: I use this feature for articles that I write. The key is that I open source the code and publish it as a Gist. That is one example of fair usage. Cloud storage is so cheap today, that you should not misuse GitHub and risk losing your account and/or your repositories (Gists are a repository). **Edit** your question to clearly state what you are trying to accomplish besides just finding free storage.

Comment: This is interesting, years ago I stumbled upon at least one free browser-based strategy game that was (until three months ago) using Gists as a "cloud" to store savegames. Literally thousands and thousands of JSON files! I wonder if the mysterious sudden cessation of new saves appearing was in response to GH pulling the plug on it...